Why does Google reCAPTCHA v3 take significantly longer after the first token request?
I'm using Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my web application. I've implemented a function 'runCaptcha' that utilizes 'grecaptcha.execute' to obtain a token. However, I've noticed that each time I call this function, it takes progressively longer to receive a new token. I'm unsure why this is happening and how to fix it.
Questions:
Why does it take significantly longer to obtain a new token after the first request, and why does this longer time remain consistent?
Is there something wrong with how I'm initializing grecaptcha or managing its instances?
Are there known performance issues with using grecaptcha.execute?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
Measurements:
I've also conducted some measurements, and the response times for obtaining the token seem to increase with each subsequent call. Here are some examples of the observed times:
first measurement:

First call: reCaptcha time: 888.7578125 ms (I am only satisfied with the first call)
Second call: reCaptcha time: 15654.778076171875 ms
Third call: reCaptcha time: 15729.93408203125 ms
Fourth call: reCaptcha time: 15709.18603515625 ms
Fifth call: reCaptcha time: 15377.43505859375 ms


second measurement

First call: reCaptcha time: 787.9111328125 ms (I am only satisfied with the first call)
Second call: reCaptcha time: 15916.755126953125 ms
Third call: reCaptcha time: 15067.10205078125 ms
Fourth call: reCaptcha time: 15615.06201171875 ms
Fifth call: reCaptcha time: 15400.135986328125 ms
Sixth call: reCaptcha time: 15716.2509765625 ms
Seventh call: reCaptcha time: 15990.376953125 ms
Eighth call: reCaptcha time: 15700.85205078125 ms

export function runCaptcha(siteKey, captchaAction) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
            reject('grecaptcha is not defined');
            return;
        }
        grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute(siteKey, { action: captchaAction }).then(function (token) {
                resolve(token);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                reject('Failed to execute reCAPTCHA: ' + error);
            });
        });
    });
};

document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.time('reCaptcha time');
    if (siteKey && siteKey.value.length > 0 && action && action.value.length > 0) {
        runCaptcha(siteKey.value, action.value)
            .then(token => {
                document.getElementById('txtCaptchaToken').value = token;
                console.timeEnd('reCaptcha time');
                if (form != null)
                    form.requestSubmit();
            });
    }
   
});


This might be deliberate as a security measure to prevent brute forcing.

Apparently reCAPTCHA does have rate-limiting - but their docs say you'll get explicit warning messages rather than delayed responses. Also, does this help?

@isherwood Of course, I have dedicated more data collection, and this is roughly always the same: 1st : 787.9111328125 ms, 2nd : 15916.755126953125 ms, 3rd: reCaptcha time: 15067.10205078125 ms , 4th: 15615.06201171875 ms, 5th: 15400.135986328125 ms , 6th  15716.2509765625 ms. There is a big difference between the first and all the others, from 0.78sec to 15-16sec

And what that shows is that it's not increasing each time. It increases once, then stays at the longer time consistently.

This is really a question for a Google engineer. Could be that they just perform additional checks on subsequent requests under the assumption that there's malicious intent.
